# normalizer property implies nilpotent group

Tags: group-theory

Why the condition that every proper subgroup H of G properly contained in $\ N_G(H)$ imply G is a nilpotent group? I know the inverse is true. Thanks.

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group, this is true, ie, if $G$ is a finite nilpotent group and $H < G$ then $H < N_G(H)$.

Comment: @AgenorAndrade, I think you confused the two directions: if $\;G\;$ is *any* nilpotent group, then any proper subgroup fulfills the normalizer condition: $\;H<N_G(H)\;$ for any proper subgroup $\;H<G\;$. For the **other** direction we must require finity: if $\;|G|<\infty\;$ and any proper subgroup fulfills the normalizer condition, then $\;G\;$ is nilpotent. This **last** condition may fail miserably if $\;G\;$ isn't finite.

Comment: Yeah, I think I forgot to say that G is a finite group. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Timbuc I apologize. Do not understand the question. I thought he wanted to conditions that proper subgroups had the Normalizer Condition. My english is not the best. sorry

Comment: @AgenorAndrade, he's asking why the normalizer condition implies nilpotency? What you wrote in your first comment is true **for any group**, finite or not. The condition the OP's asking about if fulfilled *only* for finite groups: nilpotency and the normalizer condition are equivalent then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As remarked before, this holds when $G$ is finite. In the infinite case things can become more complex.

Let us prove that each Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is normal. This implies (and is equivalent to) $G$ being nilpotent (I leave that to you). So choose $P \in Syl_p(G)$, and assume $P$ is not normal, that is, $N_G(P) \subsetneq G$.

Then certainly there exists a maximal subgroup $N$ with $N_G(P) \subseteq N$. Since $N \subsetneq N_G(N)$, it follows that $N_G(N)=G$, that is, $N \triangleleft G$. The Frattini Argument now gives $G=NN_G(P) \subseteq N$, a contradiction.

Comment: Alternatively to using the Frattini argument, one can notice that subnormal Hall-subgroups are in fact normal, since normal Hall-subgroups are characteristic.

Comment: Sorry for replying so late. I think I got it. If every p sylow group in G is normal, then G is a direct product of its p sylow subgroups(for different p). Since every p group is nilpotent, G is nilpotent.

Comment: Yes exactly! Well done.